# Running OptaPlanner examples in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, optaplanner

To run the OptaPlanner examples in IntelliJ, I followed the guide in "ReadMeOptaPlanner" in "\optaplanner-distribution-7.23.0.Final":

1. Open "pom.xml" as project in IntelliJ
2. Edit Run Configuration.

Nevertheless, I had to change the source and target version manually to avoid errors:

- File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Devployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Per-module bytecode version -> Target bytecode version -> 1.8
- File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources -> Language level -> 8

But now I get 100 errors when building the code, for example:

> Error:(24, 62) java: package org.optaplanner.persistence.common.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(25, 64) java: package org.optaplanner.persistence.xstream.impl.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(53, 12) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class SolutionFileIO
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.investment.app.InvestmentApp

or

> Error:(24, 48) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(25, 39) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.solver does not exist
>   Error:(26, 39) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.solver does not exist
>   Error:(32, 62) java: package org.optaplanner.persistence.common.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(33, 34) java: package org.optaplanner.swing.impl does not exist
>   Error:(34, 34) java: package org.optaplanner.swing.impl does not exist
>   Error:(133, 15) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class Solver
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp
>   Error:(149, 21) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class SolutionFileIO
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp
>   Information:java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

or

> Error:(23, 44) java: package com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations does not exist
>   Error:(24, 44) java: package com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations does not exist
>   Error:(25, 48) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(26, 48) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(27, 48) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution does not exist
>   Error:(28, 55) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.drools does not exist
>   Error:(29, 55) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.drools does not exist
>   Error:(30, 50) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange does not exist
>   Error:(31, 50) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange does not exist
>   Error:(32, 50) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.valuerange does not exist
>   Error:(33, 59) java: package org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoftlong does not exist
>   Error:(36, 74) java: package org.optaplanner.persistence.xstream.api.score.buildin.hardsoftlong does not exist
>   Error:(38, 2) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol: class PlanningSolution
>   Error:(39, 2) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol: class XStreamAlias
>   Error:(50, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class HardSoftLongScore
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.investment.domain.InvestmentSolution
>   Error:(98, 12) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class HardSoftLongScore
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.investment.domain.InvestmentSolution
>   Error:(102, 26) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class HardSoftLongScore
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.investment.domain.InvestmentSolution
>   Error:(111, 12) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class CountableValueRange
>     location: class org.optaplanner.examples.investment.domain.InvestmentSolution

Unfortunately the [OptaPlanner User Guide](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#runTheExamplesInAnIDE)  only says:

> Open the file examples/sources/pom.xml as a new project, the maven integration will take care of the rest.

Thanks!

- Java: 1.8
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3 x64
- OptaPlanner: 7.23.0
- OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Can you run it via `examples/runExamples.bat`?

Comment: Make sure the Maven project imported successfully: IDE should download and set up needed dependencies for project. Try refreshing project in Maven Projects tool window. It works fine for me.

Comment: @Andrey: yes, I can run it via `examples/runExamples.bat`

Comment: @Andreay: Refreshed ("Reimport All Maven Projects") it, but all dependencies in the pom.xml are still marked red ("Dependency '...' not found". Is there a way to MANUALLY download and set up the dependencies? (Maybe IntelliJ isnt allowed to access the Internet and download the dependencies within my company?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with the company's Proxy, so Maven could not download the needed files inside IntelliJ. Unfortunately it didn't show a message.

Installing and running Maven (outside of IntelliJ) manually and changing its Proxy settings and THEN use IntelliJ as my IDE now works.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij, in the "Maven Projects" side window, check your settings:

[image]

Then press these 3 buttons:

[image]